# How to begin on making the interactive section of a card game in Java

Tags: java, android, interactive

As my first big project for class, I need to make a card game using android studio. the game would pretty much be the card jitsu mini game from club penguin. I already have Card objects and everything like that, but I'm just stuck on how to begin working on the parts that the player would need to interact with. For example, how do I display a card "physically" on the game screen where it displays on the bottom left side in the players hand? how to interact with it? I'm basically stuck on the displaying and interacting with the cards. As I'm pretty new to programming I don't even really know where to begin with so every bit of help will be appreciated. I've added a picture to emphasize what I'm stuck on.
[The draft:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3TcX.jpg)

I've tried looking for how to do this on the internet but due to how specific it is I'm having a really hard time finding something useful for what I need.

Comment: What you are trying to create is called a GUI. Look up some tutorials on GUI packages in Java.

Comment: Before you start with the visual part of this, you should create and test your game model (the game and all the API you need, minus user interaction) once that's fully working, that's the time to think about visualizing it and setting it up for user interaction

Comment: Sounds like you should do a web search for general basic android tutorials. Stackoverflow is for specific questions about problems in your code, it's not a tutorial service. To answer your question people would have to type whole tutorials if not books. Luckily such books and tutorials already exist. See [ask].